# How to update ARIMA model parameters with upcoming data?

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, arima, autoregressive-models

I want to ask about ARIMA models. I am trying to forecast sales of more than 2000 products and that is why for each product, I use auto_arima function to find the model parameters. However, I want to ask is there any way to update the first output of auto_arima function together with the parameters. As I understood from these models, adding new data may change the parameters and old fitted model might not work well after adding new data. So, if is there any advice or methods that you want to share, I will be glad.
Here, how the auto arima function makes the grid search.

```
ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=1669.310, Time=0.03 sec
ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=1639.205, Time=0.28 sec
ARIMA(0,1,1)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=inf, Time=0.63 sec
ARIMA(0,1,0)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=1667.315, Time=0.20 sec
ARIMA(2,1,0)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=1613.004, Time=0.28 sec
ARIMA(3,1,0)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=1597.313, Time=0.88 sec
ARIMA(4,1,0)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=1598.531, Time=0.88 sec
ARIMA(3,1,1)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=inf, Time=0.87 sec
ARIMA(2,1,1)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=inf, Time=0.58 sec
ARIMA(4,1,1)(0,0,0)[0] intercept   : AIC=inf, Time=0.91 sec
ARIMA(3,1,0)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=1595.395, Time=0.50 sec
ARIMA(2,1,0)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=1611.042, Time=0.20 sec
ARIMA(4,1,0)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=1596.627, Time=0.58 sec
ARIMA(3,1,1)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=1584.516, Time=0.87 sec
ARIMA(2,1,1)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=1582.662, Time=0.62 sec
ARIMA(1,1,1)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=1583.646, Time=0.50 sec
ARIMA(2,1,2)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=1584.618, Time=0.93 sec
ARIMA(1,1,0)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=1637.235, Time=0.28 sec
ARIMA(1,1,2)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=1585.298, Time=0.85 sec
ARIMA(3,1,2)(0,0,0)[0]             : AIC=1586.302, Time=1.09 sec

Best model:  ARIMA(2,1,1)(0,0,0)[0]          
Total fit time: 12.986 seconds
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to do? Normally the whole dataset is split into training and testing partitions; the training partition is used to optimize the model while the testing one is used to evaluate the model. So why do you want to update the output together with the ARIMA parameters?

Comment: It is my first time with time series data, so I might be wrong with my way.I want to make sales forecasting for different products and I only have 2.5 years data. When I split my data into train and test, I split it as 133 weeks for train and 6 weeks for test. I want to forecast just for 1 week. The point that I want to understand is that while auto_arima function finds the model parameters,it takes 133 weeks as base, I thought forecast for 6 weeks might not be good indicator of best model. Also,I am not sure if arima function forecasts these 6 weeks by considering previous forecasted results.

Comment: If it does not, it is possible to see a flat line for forecasting results because one week is related with previous week. And I observed that in many of products.  So I decided to retrain model by adding one week and update for upcoming data. Seasonality is not obvious in my data but to be sure that I kept it as 52 weeks and train the data with sarimax model too. The algorithm is based on giving the model that gives lowest mse, arima or sarimax. On my other question, you may see a part of code. Again, I am open to any advice and thanks:)

Comment: I checked your other question, and based on my own experience with time series forecasting, I agree with the other comment in your other post. It's generally a good idea to use a large amount of data and multiple criteria to choose a model and stick with it (with the idea that it will outperform others in the long term).

Comment: Regarding your forecasting task, if you only need 1-week-ahead predictions, you can use week 1 - 100 as training and week 101 as test, week 2 - 101 as training and week 102 as test, etc... Then you can aggregate/average all the prediction results to compare between different approaches.

Comment: Yes, that was an useful comment and that is why I did not change the algorithm to find among three different modules. Besides that, about your last comment, do I need to take test size as that much? I have data for 139 weeks and retraining between 1-130,2-131,3-132 until 9 weeks and then train on all data to forecast for 1 week would not be enough you think? I only have three modules, arima,sarima and sarimax with fourier terms. I can add ewma etc. but arima seems good. Anyway, do you think is 9 weeks enough if I move on the way that you said? And thank you very much for your comment and idea

Comment: Based on the amount of data you have and since arima and many other forecasting models generally try to catch various types of seasonality, I think it may be a good start for you to select the number of weeks that may cover 2 years span as training (since one year consists of around 52 - 53 weeks so 139 weeks are not enough for 3 years). With that said, maybe something like week 1 - 106 as training and week 107 as testing and so on. This is just a suggestion on my part, so it's a good idea for you to test around and see for yourself. Good luck!

Comment: I understand, thank you very much!

Comment: Since this seems to be resolved to some extents, would you mind if I post this into an answer so you can accept it? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, sure. I already took your advice on my code :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221497/discussion-between-chrismoltisanti-and-minh-nguyen).

Comment: I cannot access the chat since the firewall at my office automatically blocks it.

Comment: I wrote this : By the way, It can be another way to train like : 1-103, predict 104. then 1-104, predict 105 ... What do you think?

Comment: The reason I suggested 106 is because 106 weeks can cover 2 years, thus allowing the candidate algorithms to learn the seasonality from the input data. Still, this parameter is normally based on domain knowledge, so you can test to see for yourself which one works the best.

Comment: I asked for the span, not for changing 106. sorry for misunderstanding. So you are right, it is better to test to see which one is best

Answer (score 1):

A reasonable approach can be as follows:

- Select the number of weeks in that may cover a few years (in this case 2 years) as training; this comes to around 106 weeks.
- Taking consecutive 106 weeks as training data and the next week as testing data (e.g. weeks 1 - 106 as training & 107 as testing, weeks 2 - 107 as training & 108 as testing, etc...)
- Aggregate/average over the accuracy results and choose the best model based on some criteria.
- Use this chosen model to forecast with the expectations that it will outperform other approaches in the long-term.